# Invalid method Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar::canApplyMsrp(Array ( ) )

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I am facing a serious error in magento version 1.5.1.0 while checkout. can somebody help me?
the error occurs When i enable display shopping cart sidebar,

```
Invalid method Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar::canApplyMsrp(Array
  (
  )
  )

  Trace:
  #0 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/helloresponsive/template/hellothemes/mini_cart.phtml(60): Varien_Object->__call('canApplyMsrp', Array)

  #1 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/helloresponsive/template/hellothemes/mini_cart.phtml(60): Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar->canApplyMsrp()

  #2 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2976): include('/home5/bunnygla...')

  #3 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3007): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')

  #4 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3021): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

  #5 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2312): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

  #6 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2079): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

  #7 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2030): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('miniCart', true)

  #8 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/helloresponsive/template/page/html/header.phtml(67): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('miniCart')

  #9 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2976): include('/home5/bunnygla...')

  #10 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3007): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')

  #11 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3021): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

  #12 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2312): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

  #13 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2079): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

  #14 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2030): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)

  #15 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/helloresponsive/template/page/homepage.phtml(123): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')

  #16 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2976): include('/home5/bunnygla...')

  #17 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3007): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')

  #18 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3021): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

  #19 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2312): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

  #20 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(25560): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

  #21 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12333): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()

  #22 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(9938): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()

  #23 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(9860): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')

  #24 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')

  #25 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12362): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()

  #26 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(16512): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

  #27 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(16109): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
  #28 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18506): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
  #29 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
  #30 /home5/bunnygla/public_html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
  #31 {main}
```

Comment: have you override any file recently? Have you installed any extension that override some templates? try disabling modules one by one. to see which module causes the problem.

Comment: @supal I am not sure but you can try this
http://kb.magenting.com/content/21/96/en/call-to-undefined-method-mage_catalog_helper_datacanapplymsrp-in-template-checkout-cart-item-defaultphtml.html

Comment: @Nikitas Hi Nikitas, i haven't override any file, neither i installed any extension.

Comment: last time i had a very similar problem with `invalid method` it was my theme/template fault. please try a different theme/template to see if it works.

Comment: @RohanPatil Hi Rohan, i tried your solution but didn't work for me..

Comment: Do you have a another magento installed?
you can check the canApplyMsrp() function what it returns in app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Abstract.php file so that you can trace out the results in both functions it will help you

Comment: Can you provide your site url

Comment: @supal: actually your compiler is on. Please disable it or recompile

Comment: @supal: actually your compiler is on. Please disable it or recompile. For this goto admin > tools > compiler. Disable it and clear  whole  cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason:

**Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data::canApplyMsrp()** method is implemented since Magento 1.6 version, attempts to use this method in earlier Magento versions, like Magento 1.5.1.0 or Magento 1.5.0.1 will result in fatal error.

I am assuming the error is caused at file location **Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data::canApplyMsrp() in template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml**

The solution is to check if the method **canApplyMsrp** exists like below

Change

```
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(),Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
```

To

```
if (method_exists(Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp))
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(),Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
```

I hope it helps..

Comment: this will not help as he is facing issue with Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar

Comment: Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Abstract which has the function canApplyMsrp()

Comment: yes but there is nothing like $canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->... as you posted the answer

Comment: checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml has the code for $canApplyMsrp. Also sidebar.phtml checks for msrp <?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>

Comment: My question is has the solution been applied the same way ? and if its not working, what issues @supal is facing while implementing the same ?

Comment: @Vikram I have tried by implementing the same thing but nothing changed, still same error.

Answer (score 0):

@supal: actually your compiler is on. Please disable it or recompile. For this goto admin > tools > compiler. Disable it and clear  whole  cache.